# Expected and received argument (array) match, but test fails

Tags: arrays, function, jestjs

I am testing a function which takes two arguments: a string and an array. The passed array has to match exactly with the array that is expected.

I have tried:

```
expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loadMunicipalityIDArray', muniIDArray)
```

and

```
expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loadMunicipalityIDArray', expect.arrayContaining(
    muniIDArray
))
```

but both give me errors, respectively:

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [501, 556, 599, 606, 622, 1783, 1842] as argument 2, but it was called with [501, 556, 599, 606, 622, 1783, 1842].
```

and

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ArrayContaining [501, 556, 599, 606, 622, 1783, 1842] as argument 2, but it was called with [501, 556, 599, 606, 622, 1783, 1842].
```

Why don't the tests pass?

Answer (score 0):

The name implied the function was expecting an array, but in the actual code it was being passed a set.

To be honest, Jest could have been a little more informative here, and I didn't write the original function, so I like to think the blame is not entirely my own.
Anyway, this solved it:

```
let idSet = new Set(muniIDArray)
expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loadMunicipalityIDArray', idSet)
```

and I will now also change the function name.